# Does boosting have a greater effect within it own race?

Tags: hero-deckmasters

In the game there are three races (Monster, Nature and Robot) and all three have different boost eggs. Does a Robot boost egg have a greater effect on other robot cards, or do they boost every race equally alike? And how about boosting by using cards (so not eggs), does that differ on race, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it myself, by boosting two Claw Drillbots with a 1* egg, one from robots, and one from human. The one boosted with a robot egg (the same race) ended up in level 4, with ±5% extra experience. The one boosted with a human egg, was only level 3, with ±85% experience. So for maximum effect, you should boost with eggs from the same race.

The other options is a bit silly. I was about to try it myself, but then I realized that there are no the cards the same between races.